# How to R recognize the cat() output as a variable name

Tags: r

I get the cat() output as a name of one of variable in my case but R do not interprete the output of cat() as that variable. If it possible to cat() output will be treated directly as a variable name?

Evaluated code:

```
kbwI_o <- read.xlsx(sciezka, 8, skipEmptyRows = TRUE)
rok <- '2008'
okres <- 'R1'
wielkosc1 <- 'kbwI_o'
wielkosc2 <- 'kbwM_o'
p <- cat(wielkosc1,'$',okres,".",wielkosc1,".",rok, sep = "")
p
```

I get: 
NULL

Answer (score 1):

`cat` prints to the console (or a file connection if set) and returns `NULL` invisibly. Use `paste` if you want to return something.

```
p <- paste(wielkosc1,'$',okres,".",wielkosc1,".",rok, sep = "")
p
[1] "kbwI_o$R1.kbwI_o.2008"
```