# How do I control my "cat()" printing order, when input is "cat()" output?

Tags: r

I have a function that prints a summary of data analyses using the cat() function. I want to concatenate and print this summary along with the name of the object to which the function was applied. It didn't print as expected.

I experimented with cat() and found this behavior that I don't understand:

Example A

```
> cat("a", "b", "c", sep = "\n")
a
b
c
```

Example B

```
> cat("a", cat("b"), cat("c"), sep = "\n")
bca
```

Why does this happen and how can I get Example B to print as Example A?

I understand that cat() [prints to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442278/how-to-r-recognize-the-cat-output-as-a-variable-name), but why then do I get "bca" and not just "a"?

Answer (score 0):

R evaluates the inner most function first and then moves sequentially outward. If all letters are themselves inside `cat()` and then all those are nested inside a `cat()`, then each interior one is at the same level for evaluation and evaluation starts with the first one.

```r
cat(cat("a"), cat("b"), cat("c"), sep = "\n")
#> abc
```

As you noted, in the code below, the `cat()` of "b" and "c" are at the same level for evaluation and the `cat()` that contains "a" is one level higher, so gets evaluated after.

```r
cat("a", cat("b"), cat("c"), sep = "\n")
#> bca
```

Note that if we nest the `cat()` for "c" inside the `cat()` for "b", and both those in the `cat()` for "a", then "c" prints first, then "b" then "a".

```r
cat("a", cat("b", cat("c")),  sep = "\n")
#> cba
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This makes sense! So I can't make it print like example A then?

Comment: If you have to do it with nested `cat()` statements, you could do it with: `cat(cat("a", sep="\n"), cat("b", sep="\n"), cat("c", sep="\n"))`